# How do I convert a JIRA Kanban board to a Scrum board

Tags: agile, jira, board

I initially set up a JIRA Kanban board and would now prefer to convert to a Scrum board...is there a way to do this without having to re-create the stories and epics that currently exist on the Kanban board?

Comment: While the ability to create additional boards is wonderful, keep in mind there are some features in JIRA that only apply to Scrum projects and therefore creating a "Scrum Board" does not fix root configuration issues when working with an established Kanban board in JIRA (eg. story points/estimation.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JIRA boards are simply views on projects. It is the projects that contain the stories, epics and other issue types.

This means that you can create a new board that points at an existing project.

Say for example your original Kanban board was called 'Team X'. When that was created it would have created a project called 'Team X' as well. The board would be a view on this project.

You can now create a new board of type Scrum. Make sure that when you create it you chose the option 'Board from an existing project'. Then select the project that you were using previously (in my example it is the one called 'Team X').

Now you have a Scrum board that shows all the issues that were on your Kanban board.

You don't even need to get rid of the Kanban board. Both of them will still work.

[This is the Atlassian page that explains how to create a new board](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/creating-a-board)

Answer (score 0):

Bad news is- You can't convert a board from one to the other.

Good news is- If you're using filters or projects, then you just make a scrum board that points at the same filter or project and everything will come across.

Had to do this here at AOL just last month.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you mark this question as the answer, you can help others in the future.